# What are the advantages of Promises over CPS and the Continuation Functor/Monad?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, functional-programming, promise, es6-promise

## ES6 Promises

ES6 Promises are finite state machines and thus require complex implementations. Beyond that the Promise/A+ spec comes with a lot of rough edges:

- overloaded `then` (map/chain)
- recursive flattening / then-able assimilation
- automatic lifting
- several subscribers (multicast)
- eager evaluation

Multicast distribution and eager evaluation are among other things the reasons why ES6 promises cannot be cancelled. Additionally, we can't add our own layers of then-ables with specific features, because they are immediately assimilated by recursive flattening.

I am pretty sure there were a lot of good reasons for any of these design decisions. However, now we have an invariable core language feature rather than specific, competing DSLs for asynchronous control flows in userland. Surely, interop is important, but so is the ability to evolve async  control flow features without having to take backward compatibility of the whole language into consideration.

## Continuation Passing Style

Continuation passing style abstracts from asynchronous control flows, since it gets rid of the `return` statement. To regain composability we merely need a functor in the context of continuations:

```js
const compk = (f, g) => x => k => f(x) (x => g(x) (k));


const inck = x => k => setTimeout(k, 0, x + 1);

const log = prefix => x => console.log(prefix, x);


compk(inck, inck) (0) (log("async composition:")); // 2
```

Of course, we want to compose more than two functions. Instead of manually writing `compk3 = (f, g, h) => x => k => f(x) (x => g(x) (y => h(y) (k)))`  etc., a programmatic solution is desired:

```js
const compkn = (...fs) => k => 
 fs.reduceRight((chain, f) => x => f(x) (chain), k);


const inck = x => (res, rej) => setTimeout(res, 0, x + 1);

const log = prefix => x => console.log(prefix, x);


compkn(inck, inck, inck) (log("async composing n functions:")) (0); // 3
```

This approach completely lacks exception handling. Let's naively adapt the common callback pattern:

```js
const compk = (f, g) => x => (res, rej) =>
 f(x) (x => g(x) (res), x => rej(x));

const compkn = (...fs) => (res, rej) =>
 fs.reduceRight((chain, f) => x => f(x) (chain, x => rej(x)), res);


const inc = x => x + 1;

const lift = f => x => k => k(f(x));

const inck = x => (res, rej) => setTimeout(res, 0, x + 1);

const decUIntk = x => (res, rej) =>
 setTimeout(x => x < 0 ? rej("out of range " + x) : res(x), 0, x - 1);

const log = prefix => x => console.log(prefix, x);


compk(decUIntk, inck) (0)
 (log("resolved with:"), log("rejected with:")); // rejected

compkn(inck, decUIntk, inck)
 (log("resolved with:"), log("rejected with:")) (0); // resolved
```

This is just a sketch - a lot of effort would have to be invested to achieve a proper solution. But it is a proof of concept I guess. `compk`/`compkn` are extremely simple, because they don't have to fight state.

So what are the advantages of complex ES6 promises over continuation passing style and corresponding DSLs like the continuation functor/monad?

Comment: One benefit is that promises pretty closely approximate the synchronous procedural style that most people are accustomed to, whereas what you have above would look completely alien to someone lacking a pretty extensive background in FP. For instance, I have no idea whether your example even includes a practical example of something people would want to do asynchronously. I just see a bunch of strangely-named functions being used in unfamiliar ways. It looks like you're trying to explain CFP, but you've done so in a way that would make no sense to somebody that is not already familiar with it.

Comment: Also, I believe this to be incorrect: _"Additionally, we can't add our own layers of then-ables with specific features, because they are immediately assimilated by recursive flattening."_ It's entirely possible to ensure that the promises you use in your code are wrapped in your promise-of-choice to take advantage of extra features (like the ones in bluebird).

Comment: The `then` function actually does composition. It returns a new Promise and chains promises if the callback is a promise itself and immediately resolves/rejects if it returns a value or throws an exception. It makes the code flatter and you can indeed make a promiseCompose that either tales a promise and composes `then` in a chain or perhaps return a function that will call the initial function that will produce the initial promise and then do the same chaining. IMO It's very similar to CPS except the extra tools so that we don't have to make code that constantly creates new promises.

Comment: I would like to comment that continuation passing style is not only used for asynchronous things. And *always* discarding the continuation's `return` value is *optional* – ie, you can use returned values in meaningful ways. See [delimited continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimited_continuation) for more info – and yes, I know first class continuations are likely to never see the light of day in JavaScript, but you can still use continuation (function) return values to do some really neat stuff.

Comment: I came across this old question by accident and got reminded of the discussion around the original Promises spec - https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/issues/94#issuecomment-415222385. TLDR - no, the design decisions are not based on good reasons :)

Answer (score 3):

The disadvantage of any approach that relies on functional composition is that idiomatic JavaScript code sequences are replaced with lists of named functions. Promises themselves suffer from this.

E.g. I see people do what I call *callback lite*:

```js
let foo = () => Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('foo'));
let bar = () => Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('bar'));

foo().then(bar);
```

This is *one* approach, but not the only one, and I personally dislike it, the same way I dislike any attempt at replacing JavaScript with English or action lists.

To me, a benefit of promises is that we can avoid the indirection of traditional callbacks altogether and write code in the order things happen, in a forward direction. Arrow functions help:

```js
Promise.resolve('foo')
  .then(foo => {
    console.log(foo);
    return Promise.resolve('bar');
  })
  .then(bar => {
    console.log(bar);
  });
```

However, this is arguably still an action list.

So to me, the big advantage of ES6 promises is their compatibility with [`async`/`await`](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/es7-async-functions/), which let us write idiomatic JavaScript for asynchronous code much like we would synchronous code, albeit not from top-level scope (requires Chrome or Firefox Beta):

```js
(async () => {
  console.log(await Promise.resolve('foo'));
  console.log(await Promise.resolve('bar'));
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your answer. However, you imply that function composition is not idiomatic Javascript. I disagree. The community is just not used to it. Being uncommon is something different than not being idiomatic. So incorporating `Promises` into the language was mainly an aesthetic decision, to provide synthactic sugar for asynchronous control flows. Though this is humanly comprehensible, it is somehow limiting (see my bullet points).

Comment: We wouldn't need `async`/`await`, when we were forced to work with pure functions and combinators from the beginning. `async`/`await` just gets us back to that old imperative language in the name of false "simplicity". Why would I use a language feature that doesn't even work properly with higher order functions (`await` inside an HOF)?

Comment: @ftor I think the answer is that most people don't want to be forced to work with pure functions and combinators. The "old imperative language" you mention is JavaScript to most people; they're not ready for lisp. Love it or hate it, `async`/`await` reuses existing language constructs quite well, which is a win in any language, unless you want the language to be something else. We have to agree to disagree on "idiomatic". To me, HOFs are inherently non-idiomatic, almost by definition. `x + 1` is idiomatic, `compk(inck)(x)` is not.

Comment: Well, comparing a plain expression with a powerful composition continuation is a bit like apples with oranges. Anyway, good debate. I guess 80% will agree with you.

Comment: @ftor Fair enough. Maybe `await foo() + 1` would be a fairer comparison.