# Is It Better Practice To Use Then in Express OR Nest The Functions?

Tags: node.js, express

Okay so I haven't seen this question asked yet and I am having terrible difficulty finding best practices in Express. Please let me know what is better practice this:

```
let id = req.params.id;
Story.findOne({_id:id})
    .then(story => {
        Chapter.find({storyId:story._id})
            .then(chapters => {
                res.send({story:story, chapters:chapters});
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(400).send('Failed Finding Chapters' + err);
            });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send('Failed Finding Stories'  + err);
    });
```

or This:

```
let id = req.params.id;
Story.findOne({_id:id}, (err, story) => {
    Chapter.find({storyId:story._id}, (err, chapters) => {
        res.send({story:story, chapters:chapters});
    });
});
```

Please explain. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Or `async/await` or... This is an opinion question, although Promises avoid the (start of) callback hell in the cb version.

Comment: I know it is basically opinion based but I am just trying to use best practices from the start with Express/node as I am new to it and don't want to start off using bad practices just to have to re-learn the right way later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the promises' `then` approach considered easier. One of the reasons is you rely on usual return values and the flow of code is kind of sequential. In the case of passing functions, aka callbacks it is harder to read and compose, because the code flow is cps (continuation passing style) and return values are ignored.

Here you can find more info regarding this:
[What are the advantages of Promises over CPS and the Continuation Functor/Monad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329167/what-are-the-advantages-of-promises-over-cps-and-the-continuation-functor-monad)
(it is a little bit overcomplicated, but the comments are quite good)

Comment: Thanks. The reason I asked this question is because I have been using nested functions for a while. However today I figured out how to do it with the .then statement and pass it like that. I looked at the code and found it a bit easier to understand, especially using larger, more complex functions. I just wanted to make sure that it wasn't bad practice to do it like that before I started using it for good. Thanks again for the help.